# How to Get the specific APP_Version_Name or App_Version_Code that is currently installed in user's mobile In REACT-NATIVE

Tags: react-native

I updated the App in playstore and i get the updated app version code, but Now I want to fetch the current version code that the user has installed. So then i match both the version codes, on that behalf i alert the user to update new version of that app. So how to find the current version of App the is installed in mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getversion.

you need to get the installed version from react-native-device-info#getversion and compare it with the version on your DB.